# how to compare columns in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to visually compare two columns in a data frame and it either makes a weird table with 'frequency' instead of one of the columns

I tried these options:

```
ct1=pd.crosstab(df['releaseyear'],df['score'],normalize=True)
ct1.plot()

df.plot( x='releaseyear', y='score', kind='hist')
```

and also a scatter plot which get the x and y right but I don't know how normalize it so it will only show the average of each year and not all the data

```
plt.scatter(df['releaseyear'], df['score'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no proper data which can be used to reproduce the dataframe or clue about how dataframe looks.

This answer is according to what i understood if data is like this

```
   year score
   2001 20
   2001 18
   2002 12
   2002 16
```

then first use groupby and group data according to year and apply required aggregate function.

```
df=df.groupby('year').mean().reset_index()
```

output

```
   year  score
0  2001   19.0
1  2002   14.0
```

you can then plot the data accordingly.

Comment: thanks man, this helped!